# C# - how to split a string and filter some of its entries

Tags: c#, linq, split

What's the simplest way to split the following string: "1, a, 2, a, 3, a" and then filter all the entries containing "a" to get the result: [1, 2, 3]?

Thanks,
Liz

Comment: `string.Select(x => x.IsNumber);`

Comment: @Sayse he just wants to filter out the `a`, if `b` is in there, it should not be filtered.

Comment: To expand on your question, would `1, a, 2, b, 3, a, 4, c` return `[1, 3]` for `a`, `[2]` for `b` and `[4]` for `c`?

Comment: no: [1, 2, b, 3, 4, c] for a... sorry, I should have given another example...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string[] result = "1, a, 2, a, 3, a".Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .Where(s => s != "a")
    .ToArray();
```

If you want to compare case insensitive:

```
string[] result = "1, a, 2, a, 3, a".Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .Where(s => !"a".Equals(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var results = "1, a, 2, a, 3, a".Split(',')
                                .Select(x => x.Trim())
                                .Where(x => x != "a")
                                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple regular expression combined with LINQ can manage this crudely but effectively:

```
    public static int[] NumberList(string source, string filter)
    {

        var split = Regex.Split(source, "(\\d+,\\s*\\w)");
        var list = (from s in split where s.EndsWith(filter)
                       select int.Parse( s.Split(',')[0])).ToArray();
        return list;
    }
```

The first `Regex.split` splits it into an array containing digits, a comma and a letter; the LINQ query then extracts only those items from the array that end with the filter letter, and returns the part before the comma as an array of integers.

Sample call:

```
     var result = NumberList("1, a, 2, b, 3, a, 4, c", "a");
```

returns:

```
     [1, 3]
```

(Based on your clarification, this goes beyond what you're actually asking - it will work, but it does more than is actually required)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
     int tmp;
     string[] arr = str.Split(',').
                        Where(x=>int.TryParse(x, out tmp)).
                        ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex with Linq**

```
string[] result = "1, a, 2, a, b , 3, a".Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d+$"))
    .ToArray();
```

Result

**1, 2, 3**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var arr = "1, a, 2, b, 3, a, 4, c"
    .Split(',')
    .Select(x => Parse(x))
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

The `Parse` method:

```
static int? Parse(string value)
{
    int result;

    if (int.TryParse(value, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```